# adding items to a dictionary

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I'm converting adjacency matrix to adjacency list. I need to add items to a dictionary and return it in a function, but output is the only last item. How to makes an output full list of items?

```
def adjmat_to_adjlist(adjmat: List[List[int]]) -> Dict[int, List[int]]:

    for key, i in enumerate(adjmat, start = 1):
        g = []   
        for key2, i2 in enumerate(i, start = 1):
            if i2 != 0:
                g.append(key2)
            adjlist = {key : g}
    return adjlist
```

Answer (score 1):

Before both cycles:

```
adjlist = {}
```

Then, instead of:

```
adjlist = {key : g}
```

do:

```
adjlist[key] = g
```